# Exception: Context is null, please call ToastContext.init(context) first

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, runtime-error, dart-null-safety

The issue is seen on the Toast.dart and Armodel.dart. if possible please suggest me how do i implement OCR as i followed up the codes from Pubdev but still whenever i opens my camera it crashes.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ToastContext {
  BuildContext? context;
  MethodChannel? _channel;

  static final ToastContext _instance = ToastContext._internal();

  /// Prmary Constructor for FToast
  factory ToastContext() {
    return _instance;
  }

  /// Take users Context and saves to avariable
  ToastContext init(BuildContext context) {
    _instance.context = context;
    return _instance;
  }

  ToastContext._internal();
}

class Toast {
  static const int lengthShort = 1;
  static const int lengthLong = 3;
  static const int bottom = 0;
  static const int center = 1;
  static const int top = 2;
  static void show(String msg,
      {int? duration = 1,
      int? gravity = 0,
      Color backgroundColor = const Color(0xAA000000),
      textStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
      double backgroundRadius = 20,
      bool? rootNavigator,
      Border? border,
      bool webShowClose = false,
      Color webTexColor = const Color(0xFFffffff)}) {
    if (ToastContext().context == null) {
      throw Exception('Context is null, please call ToastContext.init(context) first');
    }
    if (kIsWeb == true) {
      if (ToastContext()._channel == null) {
        ToastContext()._channel = const MethodChannel('appdev/FlutterToast');
      }
      String toastGravity = "bottom";
      if (gravity == Toast.top) {
        toastGravity = "top";
      } else if (gravity == Toast.center) {
        toastGravity = "center";
      } else {
        toastGravity = "bottom";
      }

      final Map<String, dynamic> params = <String, dynamic>{
        'msg': msg,
        'duration': (duration ?? 1) * 1000,
        'gravity': toastGravity,
        'bgcolor': backgroundColor.toString(),
        'textcolor': webTexColor.value.toRadixString(16),
        'webShowClose': webShowClose,
      };
      ToastContext()._channel?.invokeMethod("showToast", params);
    } else {
      ToastView.dismiss();
      ToastView.createView(msg, ToastContext().context!, duration, gravity, backgroundColor,
          textStyle, backgroundRadius, border, rootNavigator);
    }
  }
}

class ToastView {
  static final ToastView _singleton = ToastView._internal();

  factory ToastView() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  ToastView._internal();

  static OverlayState? overlayState;
  static OverlayEntry? _overlayEntry;
  static bool _isVisible = false;

  static void createView(
      String msg,
      BuildContext context,
      int? duration,
      int? gravity,
      Color background,
      TextStyle textStyle,
      double backgroundRadius,
      Border? border,
      bool? rootNavigator) async {
    overlayState = Overlay.of(context, rootOverlay: rootNavigator ?? false);

    _overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ToastWidget(
          widget: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: background,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(backgroundRadius),
                    border: border,
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 10, 16, 10),
                  child: Text(msg, softWrap: true, style: textStyle),
                )),
          ),
          gravity: gravity),
    );
    _isVisible = true;
    overlayState!.insert(_overlayEntry!);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration ?? Toast.lengthShort));
    dismiss();
  }

  static dismiss() async {
    if (!_isVisible) {
      return;
    }
    _isVisible = false;
    _overlayEntry?.remove();
  }
}

class ToastWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ToastWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.widget,
    required this.gravity,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget widget;
  final int? gravity;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
        top: gravity == 2 ? MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.top + 50 : null,
        bottom: gravity == 0 ? MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 50 : null,
        child: IgnorePointer(
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: widget,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mobile_vision_2/flutter_mobile_vision_2.dart';
import 'package:toast/toast.dart';

import 'arviewpage.dart';

class Armodelselect extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArmodelselectState createState() => _ArmodelselectState();
}

class _ArmodelselectState extends State<Armodelselect> {
  int _cameraOcr = 0;
  //String _textValue = "sample";
  String position = "";
  bool vision = false;
  bool showwords = true;
  bool search = false;
  late String searchtext;
  bool flash = false;
  List<OcrText> scannedwords = [];
  var DATA, DATA2, DATA3;
  final databasepost = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  final databasepost1 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  late OcrText selected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getdata();
    FlutterMobileVision.start().then((x) => setState(() {
          vision = true;
        }));
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<OcrText>> _getwords() async {
    return scannedwords;
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    SystemNavigator.pop();
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 185.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0)),
        ),
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                expandedHeight: 100,
                floating: false,
                pinned: false,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background:
                      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: <
                          Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                blurRadius: 5,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                offset: Offset(1, 3))
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.refresh,
                            color: Colors.blue[500],
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              getdata();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: !search,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  offset: Offset(1, 3))
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.camera_alt,
                              color: Colors.blue[500],
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              camerarefresh();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: !search,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  offset: Offset(1, 3))
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon:
                                Icon(flash ? Icons.flash_on : Icons.flash_off),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (flash) {
                                  flash = false;
                                } else {
                                  flash = true;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: !search,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  offset: Offset(1, 3))
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.list,
                              color: Colors.blue[500],
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (showwords) {
                                  showwords = false;
                                } else {
                                  showwords = true;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                blurRadius: 5,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                offset: Offset(1, 3))
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.search,
                            color: Colors.blue[500],
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (search) {
                                search = false;
                              } else {
                                search = true;
                              }
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: search,
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: "Keyword",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                              onChanged: (text) {
                                setState(() {
                                  searchtext = text;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              )
            ];
          },
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 0, 0),
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: _getwords(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (search) {
                    return Center(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        color: Color(0xFF21BFBD),
                        onPressed: () {
                          searchbutton(searchtext);
                        },
                        child: Text("Build Model"),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (scannedwords.length == 0 || !showwords) {
                    return Container();
                  } else if (scannedwords.length == 1) {
                    wordselected(scannedwords[0]);
                    return Container();
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: scannedwords.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  wordselected(scannedwords[index]);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.grey[100],
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          blurRadius: 5,
                                          color: Colors.black54,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 3))
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      processword(
                                        scannedwords[index].value.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        fontSize: 30,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    );
                  }
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //functions:::::::::::::::
  Future<void> camerarefresh() async {
    _read();
  }

  //read live words from camera
  _read() async {
    try {
      print(" $_cameraOcr");
      scannedwords = await FlutterMobileVision.read(
        camera: 0,
        flash: flash,
        waitTap: true,
        autoFocus: true,
        multiple: true,
        showText: true,
        fps: 30,
      );

      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        setState(() {});
      });
    } catch (e) {
      showToast("failed to recognize text");
    }
  }

  //method when ocr word list is shown
  Future<void> wordselected(OcrText word) async {
    String name = word.value.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (!checkname(name, DATA2['available'])) {
      showToast("Ar data not available check after sometime");
      changerequestword(name, DATA2['requested']);
    } else {
      print("${DATA[name]['image']}");
      objmodel modeldes = new objmodel(
          name,
          DATA[name]['size'].toString().split(","),
          DATA[name]['image'],
          DATA[name]['explain'],
          DATA[name]['type']);
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        vision = false;
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => arviewpage(modeldes),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  //for search keyword button method implementation
  Future<void> searchbutton(String word) async {
    String name = word.toLowerCase();
    print(DATA[0]);
    if (!checkname(name, DATA2['available'])) {
      showToast("Ar data not available check after sometime");
      changerequestword(name, DATA2['requested']);
    } else {
      print("image${DATA[name]['image']}");
      objmodel modeldes = new objmodel(
          name,
          DATA[name]['size'].toString().split(","),
          DATA[name]['image'],
          DATA[name]['explain'],
          DATA[name]['type']);
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
        vision = false;
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => arviewpage(modeldes),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  //check if the word exist in the available,requested word list
  bool checkname(String word, String list) {
    var listc = list.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < listc.length; i++) {
      if (listc[i] == word) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  //make wordfrequency change request to firebase database
  changerequestword(String word, String list) {
    if (checkname(word, list)) {
      int count = int.parse(DATA3[word]);
      count = count + 1;
      databasepost.child("wordfrequency").update({
        "$word": "$count",
      });
    } else {
      databasepost.child("wordfrequency").update({
        "$word": "1",
      });
      if (list == "") {
        databasepost1.child("wordlist").update({
          "requested": "${word}",
        });
      } else {
        databasepost1.child("wordlist").update({
          "requested": "${list},${word}",
        });
      }
    }
  }

  String processword(String word) {
    String postword = "";
    word.runes.forEach((int rune) {
      var character = new String.fromCharCode(rune);
      if (character == " ") {
        postword = postword + " ";
      } else {
        postword = postword + character;
      }
    });
    var w = postword.split("\n");
    postword = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
      postword = postword + w[i] + " ";
    }
    return postword.trim();
  }

  //toast method
  void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.show(text,
        textStyle: context, duration: Toast.lengthLong, gravity: Toast.bottom);
  }

  //get url for image from database
  Future<void> getdata() async {
    final reference =
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("datamodel");
    reference.once().then((DatabaseEvent snap) {
      DATA = snap.snapshot;
    });
    final reference2 =
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("wordlist");
    reference2.once().then((DatabaseEvent snap) {
      DATA2 = snap.snapshot;
    });
    final reference3 =
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("wordfrequency");
    reference3.once().then((DatabaseEvent snap) {
      DATA3 = snap.snapshot;
    });
  }
}

class objmodel {
  var size;
  String name, img_url, type, explain;
  objmodel(this.name, this.size, this.img_url, this.explain, this.type);
}
```

```
E/flutter ( 6018): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Context is null, please call ToastContext.init(context) first
E/flutter ( 6018): #0      Toast.show (package:toast/toast.dart:42:7)
E/flutter ( 6018): #1      _ArmodelselectState.showToast (package:flutter_auth_ui/screens/armodelselect.dart:456:11)
E/flutter ( 6018): #2      _ArmodelselectState._read (package:flutter_auth_ui/screens/armodelselect.dart:344:7)
E
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should call this code in your main function.

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ToastContext().init(context);//-> This part
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your `Toast` class, you have:

```
if (ToastContext().context == null) {
      throw Exception('Context is null, please call ToastContext.init(context) first');
}
```

So it is obvious that if your `context` is null, there will be an exception thrown. And in the code you have posted, there is no any `.init(...)` method called to set the context of `ToastContext` class?

You have to call `init` method of the ToastContext class wherever you are initializing the page. Better to call it in the `initState`, or wherever **BUT** before using it!